# one page site with block of screen size

Tags: css

I am working on one page site. Which has following layout.

Here is the structure.

[image]

I want every block should have min-height of the screen - header height.

```
blockHeight = screenHeight - headerHeight
```

Currently I am using jQuery to achieve this.

Is there any way to do this using only CSS3.

Comment: Use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc): `min-height: calc(100vh - headerHeight);`.

Comment: You can set an fixed height on your header and then use [viewports](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) or percentages with [calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `calc()`

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
```

Here 100vh = viewport height

60px = header height.